# Changing Screen / New Intent

Tags: android

I am trying to change screens from the first to second and back again, but with some extra variables passed. At the moment I go from 1 to 2, but when I click from 2 back to 1 it causes an error that the application stopped unexpectantly. I have issolated the problem to this part of the code. I'm not at the moment trying to pass any other variables with it just get it to change.

1st page package = max.multiplebuttons.com
Activity         = multibuttons

1st page package = max.reason.com
Activity         = reason_screen

```
public void nextquestion(){
    Intent a = new Intent();
    a.setClassName("max.reason.com", "max.multiplebuttons.com.multibuttons");
    startActivity(a);
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you did to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a.setClassName("max.reason.com", "max.multiplebuttons.com.multibuttons");
```

Your problem is here.  The class `multibuttons` isn't inside the package `max.reason.com`.

Edit:

I can't give you the exact syntax because I need to see the naming conventions, but you have to do something like this:

```
Intent a = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(a);
```

Comment: So what do I have to do. Sorry I am new to Java